# vertx server application upgrade to multi master HA cluster setup

Tags: vert.x

I have a vertx server application and a postgresql database.

I would like to develop it to a 2 node HA cluster with postgresql multi master async replication.

I have read the documentation, and I see, there is a lot of possibilities, but i am not familiar with clustering technologies.

The workload read-write ratio around 75%/25%.

What is the recommended way, to upgrade a non clustered app to a clustered one?

Comment: you add a couple of dependencies to your build and `-cluster` or `-ha` as start args.